# Can't get scatter plot on shots data in matplotlib

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

Trust, You are doing well!! I am trying to plot all the shots attempted by Liverpool against West Ham yesterday (I have scraped and cleaned the data). I am using matplotlib to draw the scatter plot that will show all the attempts by Liverpool players. I am not getting any error but I can't see the result i.e. scatter plots are not drawn.Below is my code that I have tried:

```
    import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from mplsoccer.pitch import Pitch

df_new = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv')

df_new.head(5)

data =  df_new.loc[:, ~df_new.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]

data.head(5)

#set general use colors
text_color = 'w'

fig, ax =plt.subplots(figsize=(13,8.5))
fig.set_facecolor('#22312b')
ax.patch.set_facecolor('#22312b')

pitch = Pitch(pitch_type='statsbomb', orientation='vertical',
             pitch_color='#22312b', line_color='#c7d5cc', figsize=(16,11),
             constrained_layout=True, tight_layout=False, view='half')
pitch.draw(ax=ax)

plt.scatter(data['x'],data['y'])
```

I am also attaching the screenshot of the data frame containing all columns. My 'x' and 'y' is already float and not a string. Can anyone help me to get the scatter plots? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try putting ```plt.show()``` at the end of your script

Comment: I tried but didn't work. Thanks for your answer

Comment: What are you using for your IDE?

Comment: jupyter notebook

Comment: Try putting ```%matplotlib inline```

Comment: @goalie1998 that's not an issue i guess because my plot is already aligned perfectly in the notebook cell... I tried putting that but nothing happened!!

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the problem. The figure is showing, but the data isn't? I think it should be ```pitch.scatter()``` not ```plt.scatter()```

Comment: no that will not work... the pitch is already drawn. we need matplolib to draw the scatter plot on the pitch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try this:

```py
from mplsoccer.pitch import Pitch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")
pitch = Pitch(pitch_type='statsbomb', orientation='vertical',
             pitch_color='#22312b', line_color='#c7d5cc', figsize=(16,11),
             constrained_layout=True, tight_layout=False, view='half')
fig, ax = pitch.draw()
sc = pitch.scatter(100*data["x"], 100*data["y"],
                   s=200, label='scatter', ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thanks for this try but this will not work because we need to use pyplot to draw a scatter plots. pitch function is to draw the pitch and pyplot to draw the scatter plot. I tried your solution but unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Comment: Works in my version of a jupyter notebook, and is how [mplsoccer](https://mplsoccer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/plots/plot_scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-plots-plot-scatter-py) shows to do it...

Comment: Yeah this is fine but in my case, it is not able to fetch the data points from the dataframe and matplotlib couldn't draw the plot. That's the issue I am facing. Taking customs data points are working and your answer is correct.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your dataframe then. Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Just noticed something. Try multiplying your x and y values by 100...

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Comment: Thanks, I got it done now!! You were right. I was having issues with the notebook version and also the co-ordinate's values. Now i understood the issues and debugged them!! Thanks for your patience and for helping me out.